# Android & C# Web API - Using Google OAuth2 to log-in to Web API from Android app

Tags: android, post, oauth, asp.net-web-api, google-oauth

**Background:**

I've got a C# website that requires `OAuth Google log-in` to access it's pages.

I also have an Android App where I want to access this Web API's pages (with `HttpGet-requests` and use the returned `JSON`). I did indeed make an `OAuth Google log-in` in my Android App, but I need to somehow use that to log-in on the Web API.

I used to have a `POST` on my C# website that required an `AntiForgeryToken` to log-in. Because these `AntiForgeryTokens` only exists very very short (`Session-based` and changes whenever another page is opened, even the same page in the same browser), I was forced to find a different way. (Because I tried to send a `HttpPost` in my Android App to log-in with an `AntiForgeryToken` that I received as a `response` in the last `HttpGet-request`, but this `token` just keeps changing non-stop and caused a `no-match` in my `HttpPost response`..)

**Current:**

Instead I made a new `POST-method` in my C# web project that doesn't require this `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. I've also made a `System.Web.Security.Role` for the Web API pages, and in my `API Controllers` I've added `[Authorize(Role = "web_api")]`.

When I tested this on my browser:

1. I removed all `Cookies` I have in my FireFox browser
2. I start a Private (Incognito) Window
3. And used the plug-in `RESTClient` to make the following `POST`:

   URL: `http://localhost:54408/Account/ApiLogin`

   Headers: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

   Body: `provider=Google&returnUrl=/Cart/Bestellen`

   It works with the following response: [image]

When I try to go to this same `POST` on my Android app however (using the `AsyncTask` `POST-method` at the bottom of this page), I get an *`Error 400 (OAuth2 Error)!!1`* in my `response`.

---

So, my question: How could I use this new `POST` that doesn't require any `AntiForgeryToken` to log-in with an `OAuth Google Log-in` on my Android App.

Or should I use a completely different approach to log-in with an `OAuth Google account` on my C# Web API, from within my Android app? (Could I send the `OAuth user data` from the separate `Google log-in` in the Android app itself through a different `POST`? Can I produce this `GoogleAccountsLocal_session cookie` that is somehow created after the `POST-request` myself in my Android App to use and put in the `HttpClient`? So I can get the same `response` as with the `RESTClient POST-request` above; if this is indeed the needed `cookie` to make it work?)

**TL;DR: How to log-in to an `OAuth2 Google` secured C# Web API from within an Android App (so I can send the Web API `HttpGet-requests` and get `JSON` returned), without using `AntiForgeryTokens` whatsoever?**

Thanks in advance for the responses.

---

Android `POST class`:

```
public class TaskPostAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        String response = "";
        for(String url : urls){
            InputStream content = null;
            BufferedReader buffer = null;
            try{
                // Get the baseUrl from the given url
                URL u = new URL(url);
                String baseUrl = u.getProtocol() + "://" + u.getHost();

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

                // Add the default Content-type to the Header
                post.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                // POST-request requires provider and returnUrl
                List<NameValuePair> nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("provider", "Google"));
                nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("returnUrl", baseUrl));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));

                // Send the POST-request
                HttpResponse execute = MainActivity.HttpClient.execute(post);

                // Get the response of the POST-request
                content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    response += s;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    if(content != null)
                        content.close();
                    if(buffer != null)
                        buffer.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: any answer about this?

Comment: @Emixam23 I'm afraid I don't.. I asked this question over 5 years ago when I was doing my internship for college. I'm not sure anymore whether I found an alternative method or fixed the issue. Probably the first.. I tried finding a clue in questions I asked after this one, but that didn't really give a hint either. Unfortunately I have no way to check. As I mentioned, it was for an internship at my first job. So even if they still use this application (which I doubt), I still can't look at what I did five years ago to resolve this. I also don't develop in Android at all right now.. Sorry.